# How to use a relative path for custom emmet snippets

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I created a snippets.json like this:

```json
{
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
        }
    },
    "css": {
        "snippets": {
            "bs": "block-size",
            "bbc": "border-block-color",
            "bbs": "border-block-start",
            "bbw": "border-block-width",
            "bbe": "border-block-end"
        }
    }
}
```

It's saved in my VS Code settings in the user profile (C:\Users\sebastian.laube\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\emmet\snippets.json)

How do I note the path in the setting `emmet.extensionsPath` as a relative path, and will it get synced with Settings Sync?

I don't want to set the absolute path (written above) because the username on my other system is not the same and since the settings.json is saved in the VS Code settings folder, there must be a way to use relative paths.

These settings are **not** working:

```json
    "emmet.extensionsPath": [
        "snippets/",
        "%APPDATA%\\Code\\User\\emmet\\",
        "%APPDATA%/Code/User/emmet/",
        "${appData}/Code/User/emmet/",
        "${appData}\\Code\\User\\emmet\\",
        "${env:APPDATA}/Code/User/emmet/",
        "${env:APPDATA}\\Code\\User\\emmet\\"
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no reaction and I got a bit impatient, I climbed through the source code of VS Code and found the solution in the emmet-helper package:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-emmet-helper/blob/bc294348eaf0d1f862a6b836beaa9c947be41b19/src/emmetHelper.ts#L939

There is `~` hard coded as indicatior to use the users home directory as base.
So `"~/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/emmet/"` is the solution to my question.

Sorry to answer the question my self since it's not the way Stack Overflow is intendet to be used.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's a bit dispiriting to get no replies, but kudos to you for finding and supplying the answer for others to learn from.